# How can I display the column names of a table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been researching for days now. I always get something like this (this is what I think is the best answer):

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

Yeah this one runs perfectly in SQL, but I still have no idea how I will create a PHP script to show it the same way as it does in SQL. Can anyone give me a code?

I'm really confused right now. Please help..

Answer (score 2):

without PDO:

```
$sql = "SHOW FIELDS FROM users;";
$result_sql = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error!\n");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_sql)) {
        echo $row['Field']."<br>\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  do this by in mysql [`mysql_field_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php)

**Use of `mysql_*` is discouraged   so use either `pdo` or `mysqli`**

with them you can do this by

```
mysqli_fetch_field_direct()   //for mysqli
PDOStatement::getColumnMeta() //for pdo
```

for example after [OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441153/how-can-i-display-the-column-names-of-a-table-using-php/13441180#comment18376361_13441180)

```
$sql = "SELECT * from Person";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

$name = mysql_field_name($result, 0);
```

---

explanation how to use the [`mysql_field_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php)

**Syntex**

```
mysql_field_name(data,fieldOffset) 

+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| data       | Required. Specifies which data pointer to use. The data          |
|            | pointer is the result from the mysql_query() function            |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|fieldOffset |Required. Specifies which field to start returning. 0 indicates   |
|            |the first field                                                   |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**good read**

[PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: uhm can you provide me with a php code to display the query data? and i still don't understand much of mysqli.. as well as pdo.. it doesn't matter anymore to me if mysql_* is deprecated i just need to get it done today :)

Comment: MySQL isn't deprecated, it is not recommend to use it for a new script, but they aren't going to remove it in a 5.x version..

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to retrieve data from a mysql table and then do stuff with it in php. There are several ways to do this, here is my favorite:

```
<?php
    $query="SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
            FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
            WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
            AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename'";
    $result=mysql_query($query); //This will store the whole result table in $result
    $rows=array(); //Initialize array
    while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)) $rows[]=(object) $row; //Store each row of the result table in the array $rows

    //Now you can access, for example, the third row and second column by saying:
    echo $rows[2]->name_of_second_column
?>
```

Also refer to [this tutorial.](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php_2.htm) on how to retrieve data from a database and manipulate it afterwards.

Comment: "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$status in E:\xampp\htdocs \federalcreditadvocates\admin_page\includes\functions.php on line 113"

Comment: is says that one.. and i used this one echo $rows[2]->status;

Comment: correct me if im wrong but the name of the second column is status

Comment: Are there three rows? Are there actually any results? Do `var_dump($rows)` at the very end - what does that give you?